# cannot convert value of type uibutton to expected argument string

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, share

Ive been trying to create a share button inside my tableview cell following a guide on youtube however I'm getting an error that makes no sense to me
"cannot convert value of type (VideoViewController) -> (UIButton)->() to expected argument "string"
at this line of code:

```
cell.shareButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(VideoViewController.shareAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Heres my button code

```
@IBAction func shareAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    let post = timelineComponent.content[sender.tag]
    let titleString = post.labelTitle

    let firstActivityItem = "\(titleString)"

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Change to this: `cell.shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Answer (score 2):

try like this , it should work

```
cell.shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VideoViewController.shareAction(_:)) , forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```